# serverless-offline module --> Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, es6-modules, commonjs

I am currently developing a simple lambda function using node.js with serverless.yml templates.

My project is using typescript and tsconfig is set to ESNext target version along with ESnext module as seen below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"], // DOM because @aws-sdk/client-s3 uses some of the DOM types that does not exist in node. This is the only fix I am able to find right now that suppresses all warnings..
    "rootDir": "./",
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

The package.json's type is also set to module along with requiring node version to be >= 20.0.0

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "ava": {
    "extensions": [
      "ts"
    ],
    "timeout": "30s",
    "require": [
      "ts-node/register"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/adm-zip": "^0.5.5",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.136",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.7",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.5.12",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.10",
    "ava": "^4.0.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1448.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "serverless": "^3.0.0",
    "serverless-iam-roles-per-function": "^3.2.0",
    "serverless-offline": "13.3.3",
    "serverless-plugin-datadog": "^5.21.0",
    "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2",
    "ws": "^8.16.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@turf/difference": "^6.5.0",
    "@turf/helpers": "^6.5.0",
    "@turf/union": "^6.5.0",
    "adm-zip": "^0.5.12",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.7",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "zod": "^3.22.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20.0.0"
  }
}
```

As you can see from devDependencies, it does require serverless-offline.

However, when the function is running locally using serverless-offline, the following error was hit.

[![UserFunction.js error][1]][1]

I already tried to compile everything into commonJs and that didn't work any better.

Not sure why this is the case. Has anyone who used serverless ran into this problem before?

**Edit**:
Tried to change the moduleResolution and module to NodeNext. However, the following error is encountered.

```
Error:
file:///C:/repos/proposal-docs-mirror/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/InProcessRunner.js:4
import { load } from "./aws-lambda-ric/UserFunction.js"
         ^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './aws-lambda-ric/UserFunction.js' does not provide an export named 'load'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:132:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:214:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)
```

Not sure why that would be the case. This is the same error I ran into when I set the module to commonJs. I checked the file in question (UserFunction.js). It is written with commonJs format, and I can also see a module.exports.load defined.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evo66.png